# Extension development: Can't access tab data

Tags: firefox, tor-browser-bundle

I've been trying to develop a Tor Browser extension for my own use, but can't seem to get it to access any tab content.

Just as an example, I start with this code in my primary `index.js` file:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

function logURL(tab) { 
    console.log(tab.url);
    tab.attach({
        contentScript: "if (document.body) document.body.style.border = '5px solid red';"
    });
}
tabs.on("ready", logURL);
tabs.open("");
```

This will both open a new tab and change the border of any tab that has content *in regular Firefox*, but will only open a new tab in Tor Browser 5.5.5. No matter what I do, I can't seem to access tab content.

Is there some setting I need to change to enable this behavior in Tor Browser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, ther're some tweaks in FF code for TBB, and you're hitting one of them. The purpose of these tweaks is precisly *full prevention* of "jailbreaking", i.e. requesting data from the place different from your point-of-execution. such tweaking is called/"referred as" sandboxing

Comment: I asked the TBB developers and actually there are /no/ tweaks in TBB in this regard. It might be the case that @rob accidentally hit something. However if so, this was not on purpose.

Comment: They do isolation as much as possible, and it is done - as far as I know - in LTS FF tweaked to be a Tor browser. Can you please provide your question and their answer?